# Mirah Android Cast HowTo?

Tags: android, ruby, mirah

Hello I was wondering how to do the following:

```
CheckBoxPreference mCheckBox = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("key");
```

except in [mirah](http://github.com/mirah/mirah)?                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                This cast here is what I don't know how to translate into mirah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, casting in Mirah is in the form of wrapping the object in the form of `TypeToCastTo(ObjectToCast)`, for example:

`mCheckBox = CheckBoxPreference(findPreference("key"));`

Comment: thx for the response. When I try the following `@mEnable = CheckBoxPreference(findPreference("enable"))` I get the error `undefined method 'aload' for nil:NilClass @mEnable = CheckBoxPreference(findPreference("enable"))` when I convert from mirah to java

Comment: I believe `findPreference("enable")` should be `self.findPreference("enable")`... I've only glanced at using Mirah, so I may be missing something :/

Comment: well adding self didn't help but I got a few other ideas to try.

Comment: The `aload` thing is a compiler bug, could you file an issue at https://github.com/mirah/mirah/issues ?

Comment: @BaroqueBobcat the issue can be found at [https://github.com/mirah/mirah/issues/181](http://https://github.com/mirah/mirah/issues/181)